# Mathematical expressions for selections

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How would you go about writing an expression for:

"The number of subsets of $\{1,2,3, . . . ,10\}$ with **three elements**, that contain **at least one odd** number and **at least one even** number."

I can work out an expression for each of these, but I am not sure how to write an expression that *combines all three conditions* ($3$ elements, at least one odd & even) - there would be less subsets for an expression when conditions are combined.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What would be your expressions for each condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count all 3-element subsets and then subtract the ones that are all odd or all even. This gives ${10 \choose 3} - {5 \choose 3} - {5 \choose 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $E := \{2,4,6,8,10\}$ the set of even numbers and $O = \{1,3,5,7,9\}$ the set of odd numbers. Then you can describe your sets $M \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, 10\}$ by the single condition

$$|M \cap E| \cdot |M \cap O| \geq 2.$$

If that is better than having multiple conditions is a different question of course.